# Accessing 2 models with 1 controller in Java MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Is accessing 2 models with 1 controller in Java MVC alright?
The code looks similar to this:
This is the 1st model

```
public class People {

    private String id, name;

    public People(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;        
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I'm still not sure about PeopleList class necessity. This is the 2nd model.

```
public class PeopleList extends ArrayList<People>{

    @Override
    public boolean add(People e) {
        return super.add(e);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return super.size(); 
    }    
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class PeopleListController {

    PeopleList peopleList;

    public People findPeopleById(String id) {

        People person = new People("", "");
        for (People p : peopleList) {   
            if (p.getId().equals(id)) { 
                return p;
            }
        }
        return person;
    }    
}
```

In the peopleListController, I accessed people using p.getId().

- Is it alright?  If it is, then it means I don't need to create
  peopleController.
- Or should I access p.getId() via a new controller
  called peopleController?
- Or should I just remove the peopleList class
  and make an arrayList in this controller? ArrayList peopleList

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I do not see the advantage of creating a subclass of ArrayList in your case.

Comment: @Enzokie yeah me too.  I just realized it when I was writing the question.  I guess I'll try the third choice

Comment: Enzokie Is right, your PeopleList class is pointless just use `ArrayList<People> peopleList;` other then that it's fine. I don't know from where you got the idea that controller can only use one model class but this is not the case. I also don't see what makes your `PeopleListController` class a controller, this is still model.

Comment: @Oleg I just thought it'll make the controller too complicated by handling too many models and a friend said that I should make it per model.  I'm still not sure about that though. I don't know many people who really care about the concept to discuss it. Thanks for the answer about the controller.